# How can I default a field (A) to a value of a field (B) and still be able to edit the field and backdate?

Tags: acumatica

Application Date to default Document Date:

[image]

```
 protected void ARPayment_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e, PXRowSelected InvokeBaseHandler)
{
  if(InvokeBaseHandler != null)
    InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);
  var row = (ARPayment)e.Row;
 
        if (row != null)
          {
                              
                row.AdjDate = row.DocDate;
                row.AdjFinPeriodID = row.FinPeriodID;
            
          }

}
```

> The code defaults the fields as required but Application date cannot be edited hence backdating cannot be done

```
protected void ARPayment_AdjFinPeriodID_FieldDefaulting(PXCache cache, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e)
{
  
  var row = (ARPayment)e.Row;
  row.AdjFinPeriodID = row.FinPeriodID;
  
}



protected void ARPayment_AdjDate_FieldDefaulting(PXCache cache, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e)
{
  
  var row = (ARPayment)e.Row;
  row.AdjDate = row.DocDate;
  
}
```

> Using field defaulting gives index out of range error
>
> By Adding a condition to check the status of the document it seizes to work

```
protected void ARPayment_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e, PXRowSelected InvokeBaseHandler)
{
  if(InvokeBaseHandler != null)
    InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);
  var row = (ARPayment)e.Row;
 
        if (row != null && row.Status == "Open")
          {
                              
                row.AdjDate = row.DocDate;
                row.AdjFinPeriodID = row.FinPeriodID;
            
          }

}
```

Comment: You are on the right track with the FieldDefaulting event handler, but the RowSelected event handler should not be used to set values.  For unbound fields, you can use RowSelecting, but I believe this is a bound field.  In other words, regardless of the value, you are forcing it to a new value every time you retrieve the record... hence the inability to manually change it.  The backdating issue would depend on whether you are allowed to backdate.  Generally, backdating is frowned upon because people may try to affect a closed period, but you would have to discuss that with your finance group.

Answer (score 0):

The `RowSelected` event is not an initialization event. It is run on every callback to the server.

The `FieldDefaulting` event should assign the default value using the `NewValue` property of `PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs` argument parameter.

> Using field defaulting gives index out of range error

That should not happen in your FieldDefaulting handler because there are no index access operations. I can't reproduce this issue. Remove all other customization code, keep only the FieldDefaulting event and this error should disappear.

There is another issue though. The `DocDate` value is always null when I debug the FieldDefaulting event. When I pass a valid Date value for initialization it does work as expected on new payments. Example:

```
using PX.Data;
using System;

namespace PX.Objects.AR
{
    public class ARPaymentEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<ARPaymentEntry>
    {
        public void ARPayment_AdjDate_FieldDefaulting(PXCache cache, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e)
        {
            ARPayment row = e.Row as ARPayment;

            if (row != null)
                e.NewValue = new DateTime(2077, 01, 01);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]